# Prove that the complex numbers for which the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{3^n}{z^n+z^{-n}}$ converges is an open set of $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, power-series

My ideas was to find the radius of convergence of the series using the ratio test that says

$$R = \frac{1}{\lim_{n\to\infty}|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|} = \lim_{n\to\infty}|\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}|$$

However, I get the following result:

First, $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{3^n}{z^n+z^{-n}} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{3^n z^n}{z^{2n} + 1} $$

So,
$$R = \lim_{n\to\infty}|\frac{3^n z^n}{z^{2n} + 1} \cdot \frac{z^{2n+2} + 1}{3^{n+1} z^{n+1}}|$$
$$ = \lim_{n\to\infty}|\frac{1}{3z}\frac{z^{2n}z^2 + 1}{z^{2n}+1}|$$
$$ = |\frac{1}{3z} \cdot z^2|$$
$$ = |\frac{z}{3}|$$

But I think I should not be getting any z in my final expression.
What should I do to fix this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How do you go from$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{1}{3z}\frac{z^{2n}z^2 + 1}{z^{2n}+1}\right|$$to$$\left|\frac{1}{3z} \cdot z^2\right|?$$

Comment: This is not an entire series... what is asked basically is to prove that if this series converges at $z_0$, it does on a neighborhood of $z_0$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos As n goes to infinity the second fraction would go to $z^2$. Is that correct?

Comment: It depends on the module of $z$

Comment: Please remove the word "radius of convergence" it does not suits your functions series.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Renamed your series $f_n$ for more convenience.

First we can notice that if $f_n(z) = f_n(z^{-1})$, so we only need to deal with $|z|>1$ there is a "symmetry" on both sides of the unit circle.

If $|z|>3$, it is clear that $f_n(z)$ converges since it absolutely converges. If $1\leq|z| < 3$ we clearly have $|f_n (z)| \to \infty$. Then we need to deal with the case $|z| = 3$.

In this case, $a_n(z) = \frac{3^n}{z^n +z^{-n}} = \frac{1}{\left(\frac{z}{3}\right)^n +(3z)^{-n}}$, so $|a_n| > \frac{1}{\left|\frac{z}{3} \right|^n + |3z|^{-n} } > 1/2$ for $n$ sufficiently large. Hence $f_n(z)$ does not converge.

That means that the set $C$ of points where $f_n$ converges is
$$C = \{ z \in \mathbb{C}^* \mid |z|< \frac{1}{3}\} \cup \{ z \in \mathbb{C}^* \mid |z|> 3\}$$
which is open.

If we denote $f$ the limit, a good approximation of $f$ is:

- for $|z|>3$: $\quad\frac{z}{z-3} -1 = \frac{3}{z-3}$.
- for $|z|<\frac{1}{3}$: $\quad\frac{1}{1-3z} -1 = \frac{3z}{1-3z}$.

Comment: What is $\mathbb{C}^*$ ?

Comment: $\mathbb{C}^* = \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$

Comment: that makes sense, thanks

Comment: Minor correction, on the line "In this case," it should be $|a_n| > \frac{1}{\left|\frac{z}{3} \right|^n - |3z|^{-n} }$.

Comment: @copper.hat I don't think so, the biggest possible value for the denominator comes from the triangle equality hence its a +, (things are reversed)

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace Sorry, I don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: @copper.hat no problem it happens to the best of us (I had to rewrite it 3 times to be sure haha).

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Use the ratio test to conclude that

- the series converges if $z$ satisfies either $0<|z| < \frac{1}{3}$ [where the $z^{-n}$-term in the denominator dominates] or $|z|>3$ [where the $z^n$-term in the denominator dominates]
- the deries *diverges* for $z$ satisfying $\frac{1}{3} \le |z| \le 3$ ...
- and then putting the above together, that the series converges if **and only if** $z$ satisfies either $0<|z| < \frac{1}{3}$ or $|z|>3$, which is an open set.

With that said, you made an incorrect logical leap near the bottom in your proof. What if say $z$ satisfies $|z|<1$? Then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{z^{2n}z^2+1}{z^{2n}+1}$ is $1$ [and not $z^2$ as you put], as $z^{2n}$ vanishes.